# Date Formatting Issues "YYYY-MM-DD" - no override/culture settings are working

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have spent over a week of on and off again trying to solve this and I am coming up empty.

I am writing an SSIS package and need to create a dynamic date for when the record is inserted (i'm using a script component to do this). I need it in the format "yyyy-MM-dd" as per the rest of our database.

No matter what I try, it is constantly outputting the date as "dd-MM-YYYY" which is causing an overflow error as no day can be "2021" for example.

Here is my latest attempt where I am trying to explicitly set the culture info and the pattern formatting.

I read that the date format can be affected by your computers system date format settings. My computers date format is set to "dd-MM-yy". Which does match the output i'm getting from my code.

**Assuming I CANNOT adjust the server or system settings, how do I output my date in the "yyyy-MM-dd" format?**

```
 var culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US");
var dateformat = new DateTimeFormatInfo();
dateformat.FullDateTimePattern = "dddd, mmmm dd, yyyy h:mm:ss tt";
culture.DateTimeFormat = dateformat;
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = culture;
            

//CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
//IFormatProvider culture = new CultureInfo("en-US", true);
updateDateTime = DateTime.ParseExact("2021/02/01", "yyyy/MM/dd", culture);
```

You can see in my code example above, the final line, i'm currently explicitly writing out a date and updateDateTime should be the final yyyy-MM-dd value I need.

Thank you so much for your help. This is driving me insane.

Comment: Your approach makes no sense, as `updateDateTime` would be a `DateTime`. `DateTime`s do not have formatting info at all; your problems presumably come when the `DateTime` is being converted to a string (however that is happening). If your destination column is not of type `DATE` or `DATETIME` (as it properly should be) you'll need to take care of the string conversion yourself (`DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")`).

Comment: The destination (final SQL column) is of the type "datetime". When I check the metadata in the package, my "updateDateTime" is DT_DBTIMESTAMP2 and my sql is DT_DBTIMESTAMP2, according to the SSIS metadata.

I have tried this in the past and again now and the code breaks here.

`String updateDateTimeStr = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");`

`DateTime updateDateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(updateDateTimeStr, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);`

Comment: You *do not* need to involve `ParseExact` in this scenario, ever. You are not trying to turn a string into a `DateTime` so this is never relevant. At worst you need to troubleshoot why string conversion is happening on the `DateTime` (and SSIS can be a right bitch with that -- double-check all your column mappings and types thereof), but you never need to be concerned with the other direction (parsing strings into `DateTime`s), at least not from what you've described.

Comment: @Seere dates have no format. End of story. You don't need a script component to calculate the current date. A simple `Created` column with `date` type and `GETDATE()` as the default would do the same job. In SSIS the `System::StartTime` system variable provides the package start time, so there's no need for scripting either. You can enter that variable into any date-typed column

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos THANK YOU. Your comment got it working. I did not know about a derived column in SSIS and using that I was able to get it working. I think I also understand what you mean by dates have no format and it answers a lot of questions I had when reading various stack overflow answers around datetime problems. Is there someway to set you as the "answer"? Thank you so much again.